# IntelliJ Create path, forgets new files

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the "Version control / Create Patch" feature of IntelliJ.
It works fine, but it forgets to add the new files.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably [facing this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-72074).

However, your problem may be different. Note that you need to add new files to the version control, if they are shown as **Unversioned**, patch will not contain them.